# log4 net rolling - Remove special character in file name

Tags: .net, configuration, log4net

I have added below code and output file name is **%date.filename.txt** . Please suggest how to remove % character in the file name.

```
 <appender name="SLSILogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" >
  <converter>
    <name value="logfilename" />
    <type
   value="FilenamePatternConverter" />
  </converter>
 <conversionPattern
    value="%property{TestURL}%" />
</file>
<appendToFile value="true" />
<rollingStyle value="Date" />
<staticLogFileName value="false" />
<!--<datePattern value="yyyy.MM.dd.%property{MachineName}%'.log'" />-->
<datePattern type="log4net.Util.PatternString">
   <conversionPattern
    value="yyyy.MM.dd.%property{MachineName}%'.log'" />
</datePattern>

<lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     </layout>
```

```
expected file name : **date.filename.txt**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this idd with a conversion pattern, the right patterns is:

```
<file value="c:\temp\" />
<datePattern  type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="yyyy.MM.dd.'%property{log4net:HostName}.log'" />
```

Comment: No still that special character Persists..  **%2015.08.04.filename.txt** is the file that got generated.

Comment: The % seems to come from your file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="%property{TestURL}**%**"